# Is there a way to edit the opacity of a font?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, opacity

I've seen plenty of stuff for changing the opacity for jpanel and images, but no matter how hard I look I can't find anything for changing the opacity of the font and only the font. Preferably would like to not have to import a library if possible.

Just normal font code:

```
   Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 15);

   setFont(font);
```

Comment: when you draw text, you use a color/paint - that paint supports transparency

Comment: could you also provide code wheren we can seewhere you actually draw that string?  What technology are you using (swing paint differs slighty from javafx and that is different to android)?

Comment: I'm using swing, but I think I've figured out how to do it by editing the color like you said in the first comment, the help is much appreciated

Comment: To put it a slightly different way, Java has to render the text (a vector format) to the screen (a raster format). The process is known as [rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation).

Answer (score 0):

In Swing you should extend LabelUI to achieve label opacity.
Try this

```
    class OpacityLabelUI extends BasicLabelUI {

        private int alpha = 0x55;

        public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintEnabledText(JLabel l, Graphics g, String s, int textX, int textY) {
            int mnemIndex = l.getDisplayedMnemonicIndex();
            g.setColor(applyAlpha(l.getForeground()));
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(l, g, s, mnemIndex, textX, textY);
        }

        private Color applyAlpha(Color color) {
            color = new Color((color.getRGB() & 0xffffff) | (alpha << 24), true);
            return color;
        }
    }
```

and then

```
label.setUI(new OpacityLabelUI());
```